# imort CSV data to Mysql table 

Tags: mysql, database, csv

i have one csv file which contains library group and it's data...

group consider as sheet and for each sheet contains phrase name and phrase value...

I want to insert this csv data to two different table using mysql how can i ?

suppose i have 2 table like

```
phrase_library_group
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| GROUP_ID    | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| GROUP_NAME  | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

phrase_list
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| PHRASE_ID   | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| PHRASE_NAME | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| PHRASE_DESC | varchar(500) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| GROUP_ID    | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

here in image Additional_meds/Antibiotic Warnings/... are groups

and each group contains different phrases..like Additional_meds contains total 12 records as see below.

csv like [image]

Comment: do you use any certain IDE to work on MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it natively in MySQL, this should be much faster and consume less ressources.
Create a table in MySQL containing all fields from your CSV, i.e.

```
tmp_phrases
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| GROUP_NAME  | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| PHRASE_NAME | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| PHRASE_DESC | varchar(500) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

load data from CSV into this table via `LOAD INFILE` statement inside MySQL, i.e.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '~/phrases.csv' INTO TABLE tmp_phrases FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"';
```

After that you can split your data with two `INSERT` statements.

```
INSERT INTO phrase_library_group (GROUP_NAME)
    SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_NAME FROM tmp_phrases

INSERT INTO phrase_list (PHRASE_NAME,PHRASE_DESC,GROUP_ID)
    SELECT x.PHRASE_NAME,x.PHRASE_DESC,y.GROUP_ID
    FROM tmp_phrases x
    INNER JOIN phrase_library_group y ON x.GROUP_NAME=y.GROUP_NAME
```

Comment: first load Query insert only top most record..not all data

Comment: this `LOAD` statement takes all rows from file, maybe there's a non well formed field or row terminator

Answer (score 0):

Use:  [file_get_content()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to read the file.

Use:  [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to parse the data thus fetch into arrays and then insert using whatever mysql functions/classes you are using.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134967/insert-comma-separated-records-in-table/8135024#8135024  - For more help